# Laravel 7 - How to disable logging?

Tags: laravel, logging, disable

I'm using Laravel 7.x and I want to write my own logs. I've configured config/logging.php and achieved writing my log entries, but Laravel is also writing its own log entries in my log file.

How do I disable automatic Laravel log entries and keep my own log writing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can create your separate your log file and write your log information.

Comment: To write my logs using the loggin.php configurations I can start writing my logs. The problem is that Laravel also uses my files to write his own logs.

Comment: I am suggest to you create your own log file and update frequently as per required time. `Laravel` is create own log file for error tracking.

Comment: How do I do that? Because, Laravel is writting on my log file. I've defined my log file and Laravel is writting on it.

Comment: Could you show your logger.php config, please? Are you using `logger()` function to make records in your log file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make your own log channel. Edit your `config/logging.php`:

```
    ....
    'channels' => [
        ....

        'your-channel-name' => [
            'driver' => 'daily',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/your-channel-log-file-name.log'),
            'level' => 'debug'
        ],
    ],
    ....
```

After that you could make records to `your-channel-log-file-name.log` file like this:

```
\Log::channel('your-channel-name')->debug('This is my debug message');
```

It's like using `logger()` function.

Comment: Thank you Petr. Never thought about that approuch.
BTW, to disable Laravel 7.x logs, within this solution, just leave an empty array in the channels of the stack options:

`code
'channels' => [
        'stack' => [
            'driver' => 'stack',
            'channels' => [],
            'ignore_exceptions' => false,
        ],
`

Answer (score 0):

You can try given solution for you problem.

Please include following namespace in your controller or class file.

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
```

Now you can create log directory and file for your log writting.

```
$logPath = storage_path() . '/custom_logs/';
$log = $logPath . 'custom-file-log-'.Carbon::today()->format('d-m-Y') . '.log';        
if (!File::exists($logPath)) {
   File::makeDirectory($logPath, $mode = 0777, true, true);
}
```

Now write errors or custome information in to Log file.

You can log text message in log file

```
$message = "It is first custom  log";
File::append($log, Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')." -- ".$message . PHP_EOL);
```

You can log array in log file.

```
$message = ['A'=>'B', 'C'=>'D'];
File::append($log, Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')." -- ".print_r($message,true). PHP_EOL);
```

Thanks!!